# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when fragment recalled

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, exception, adapter

I have a nested recyclerview & Implemented `OnClickListener()` in the nested recycler and replace fragment on its click. In `onBindViewHolder` of 1st recycler I'm setting new adapter according to data that I get from server.

1. If data hold type `Category` setting Category adapter
2. If data hold type `Item` setting Item adapter

Here is the code how I'm setting

```
if (myCategoryList.size() > 0 && isCategory) {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(myCategoryList);
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
            isCategory = false;
        } else {
            if (myItemListOfList.size() > 0) {
                if (myCategoryList.size() > 0) {
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(myItemListOfList.get(position - 1));
                    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                } else {
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(myItemListOfList.get(position));
                    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
```

When I run the program Everything works fine. When I click on `view` of type `Category` it works fine as well. But when I click on `view` of type `Item` it open the next fragment successfully, the problem come when I press back button it take me to the previous fragment where the above code is. Then the `if statement` is not executing so I'm getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` on the line where the code is `position - 1` in above code.

So I wanna know Why on back press from `Item Fragment` if statement does not execute and why it execute on back press from `Category Fragment`.

`isCategory` is global variable and is true by default. I also try to set it true in constructor as well but the problem is same.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Issue must be here. The value of `position` must be holding some unexpected value.

```
itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(myItemListOfList.get(position - 1));
```

Can you change your code like and try once

```
if (myCategoryList.size() > 0 && isCategory) {
            categoryAdapter = new CategoryAdapter(myCategoryList);
            holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(categoryAdapter);
            isCategory = false;
        } else {
            if (myItemListOfList.size() > 0 &&  position <= myItemListOfList.size()-1 ) {
                if (myCategoryList.size() > 0) {
                    position = ((position -1) < 0 ? 0 : position-1);
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(myItemListOfList.get(position));
                    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                } else {
                    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(myItemListOfList.get(position));
                    holder.recyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapter);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: there is no execption now but it do not show items of last index.

Comment: can you tell me what are the values of position?

Comment: When position is 0 it set the category adapter otherwise Item. When Exception occur the value is -1

Comment: its still the same. I believe my code was right can you point out why its says index -1 when back press otherwise there is no issue.

Comment: This is the execption `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=12; index=-1`

Comment: Anyway Thank you for your time. from you code I got the idea. now adding `position > 0` condition in my above code work fine, as `if (myCategoryList.size() > 0 && position > 0)`.

Comment: 1 up for you for you help